# How to extract a link between paragraph tags

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to fetch a link which is in between p tags, But my result is "/playlist" and i need the link like "song/54826/father-friend".
Been on this for hours now. Help me out please

```
<div class="track__body">
        <p class="track__track">
            <a href="song/54826/father-friend" class="track__title" id="zwartelijst_song" data-track="">Father &amp; Friend</a>
            <span class="track__artist" data-artist="" id="zwartelijst_artist">Alain Clark</span>
        </p>
        <a href="/playlist" class="track__playlist">
         
        </a>
```

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="some url";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$links = [];
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document ->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($document );
$anchorTags = $xPath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"track__body\"]//a/@href");
foreach ($anchorTags  as $anchorTag) {
    $links[] = $anchorTag->nodeValue;
}
echo $links[1];
```

Comment: The link you are after is in `echo $links[0];` as it is the first link it finds.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your xpath so it scopes to the right element.

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document ->loadHTML('<div class="track__body">
        <p class="track__track">
            <a href="song/54826/father-friend" class="track__title" id="zwartelijst_song" data-track="">Father &amp; Friend</a>
            <span class="track__artist" data-artist="" id="zwartelijst_artist">Alain Clark</span>
        </p>
        <a href="/playlist" class="track__playlist">
        </a>');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($document );
$anchorTags = $xPath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"track__body\"]/p[@class=\"track__track\"]/a/@href");
foreach ($anchorTags  as $anchorTag) {
    echo $anchorTag->nodeValue;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/YY0dD

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. and this part:loadHTML('<div class="track__body">
        <p class="track__track">
            <a href="song/54826/father-friend" class="track__title" id="zwartelijst_song" data-track="">Father &amp; Friend</a>
            <span class="track__artist" data-artist="" id="zwartelijst_artist">Alain Clark</span>
        </p>
        <a href="/playlist" class="track__playlist">
        </a>');is dynamic

Comment: This is a functional example of the code you provided. You can put it back to `$document ->loadHTML($html);`. The only part you need to change is the xpath, `$anchorTags = $xPath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"track__body\"]/p[@class=\"track__track\"]/a/@href");`

Comment: Actually, Nigel is correct as well, you could use your xpath and then just pull the first link as well. https://3v4l.org/QIDCf That seems a bit more problematic down the road though. I'd target the element you want. Otherwise you will need to iterate over and determine which one is correct.

Comment: unfortunately nothing shows when i do that

Comment: Your code must be different from what you provided. You can see functional code on both 3v4l.org links. Update question with code, use `var_dump` for `$html` bit, could be double encoded

Comment: ```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url="https://www.nporadio2.nl/playlist";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$links = [];
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document ->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXPath($document );
$anchorTags = $xPath->evaluate("//div[@class=\"npo-track__body\"]//a/@href");
foreach ($anchorTags  as $anchorTag) {
    $links[] = $anchorTag->nodeValue;
}
echo $links[1]; 


?>```                     I Just want to scrape the NOW-PLAYING url

Comment: Should just need to change class names and it works, https://3v4l.org/2UFXm. The `href` has no value though. I think JS might be being used here to put the `card--playlist` into this element.